# Undefined method error for CSV class

Tags: csv, methods, undefined

I am following this tutorial for exporting CSV:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

However, I am getting an "undefined method '<<' for CSV:Class

The code snippet being highlighted in the error is:

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    CSV << column_names #this row is highlighted in the error
    all.each do |opportunity|
      CSV << product.attributes.value_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

My config/application:

```
require 'rails/all'
require 'csv'
```

Thanks!
Please note that I am only 2:30 into the video.

Comment: It's typo, use small case `csv` instead of `CSV`

Answer (score 0):

In the Fifth line

```
CSV << product.attributes.value_at(*column_names)
```

change it to

```
CSV << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
```

Now it'll work fine. Hope this helps.